# iOS CoreBluetooth Notifications

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, core-bluetooth, iot, bluetooth-lowenergy

Squirrels on my balcony eat my jalapeños. I pointed a camera to the place where my jalapeños grow and using a simple motion detection software on my computer on the balcony I know when squirrels show up.

I figured out how to establish a Bluetooth Low Energy communication between my computer and my iPhone (my computer is the central and the smartphone is a peripheral).

Is there a way how to invoke a push notificaiton using Bluetooth Low Energy that shows up on my phone whenever my camera detects a squirrel? I want to know if it is possible without an Internet connection.

Comment: APNS technology stack won't work without Internet connection.

Comment: I'm impressed by your squirrels. The ones around here wouldn't touch jalapeños.

Answer (score 0):

In a word, no. Push notifications require an internet connection. However, do you specifically want APNS, or do you just want a way to wake up your app and display a message to the user when you receive a BLE message from your computer?

I believe you can set up your iPhone app to get BLE notices from the background. If you can do that then you can code your app to trigger a LOCAL notification (different from a push notification, but similar in terms of the UX)

Comment: Hey Duncan, thank you so much for answering! It doesn't necessarily has to be a push notification, a simple wakeup message/signal would be sufficient

Comment: Take a look at Arduino.

Comment: @EvgenyKarkan, what does Arduino have to do with the question? The OP already has a motion-triggered camera. Now he wants to send BLE-based notifications to his phone when the camera detects motion. The Arduino would make a good interface for the camera, but he'd still need a way to notify his phone when the camera detected a squirrel.

Comment: Well, ok @DuncanC you win, but anyway OP plz look at this article - http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-make-a-simple-arduino-alarm-system/ , who knows - maybe you will switch your mind to `Arduino-way` doing your squirrel hunt ;)